# Connecting to Postgres sql with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I am running postgressql on a docker container. I am trying to connect to postgres via python and display the tables below is the code that I am using to connect to postgres:

```
import psycopg2

conn_string = "host='192.168.99.100:15432' dbname='PREDICTIVE_DS_POSTGRESQL' 
user='ds_user' password='ds_user'"
print("Connecting to database\n ->%s" % (conn_string))
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
print("Connected!\n")
```

Then I use the below Python code to display the existing tables within postgres:

```
def table_exists(con, table_str):

exists = False
try:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select exists(select relname from pg_class where relname='" 
    + table_str + "')")
    exists = cur.fetchone()[0]
    print("exists")
    cur.close()
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print(e)
    return exists

    def get_table_col_names(con, table_str):

    col_names = []
  try:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from " + table_str + " LIMIT 0")
    for desc in cur.description:
        col_names.append(desc[0])
    cur.close()
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print(e)
```

However, it is not working at all. It says that it cannot connect translate host name "192.168.99.100:15432" to address: Unknown host. However, the container is up and running and that is the host name. Additionally, I don't know whether the rest of the code will work once it connects.

Comment: The host name is 192.168.99.100, you have to specify the port separately.

Comment: Try something like this: `conn_string = "host=192.168.99.100 port=15432 dbname=PREDICTIVE_DS_POSTGRESQL"`

Comment: I have changed the code like this:                                                 
conn_string = psycopg2.connect(host="192.168.99.100", port:"15432", database="PREDICTIVE_DS_POSTGRESQL", user="ds_user", password="ds_user"). However, the problem still persists I receive invalid syntax

Comment: try:  conn_string = "host='<hostname>' dbname='<dbname>' user='<user>' password='<password>' port='<portnumber>' " and then connect using - psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

Comment: Same syntax error in that line

Comment: Have you changed the default port of PostgreSQL? Because it is 5432 instead of 15432.

Answer (score 0):

Have your database credentials defined in a separate file.

For example, have a file called database.ini and define it like this:

```
[creds]
host=192.168.99.100
port=15432
database=PREDICTIVE_DS_POSTGRESQL
user=ds_user
password=ds_user
```

Have another config parser file to parse this. Call it config.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
try:
    import configparser
except:
    from six.moves import configparser


def config(section,filename='database.ini',):
    parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
    parser.read(filename)
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params = parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]] = param[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} not found in the {1} 
file'.format(section, filename))
    return db
```

Now, in your main file, import your config function like this:

```
from config import config
```

and connect like this:

```
    dbParams = config("creds")
    con = psycopg2.connect(**dbParams)
```

Comment: hi @sindhu_sp sorry for the late reply. I just tried it it's not working. I don't get any errors but it's not reading the db